# Fix corrupted characters (e.g. umlauts) in a string using ORACLE SQL and convert it to proper UTF-8

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I currently have an ORACLE table which, in one column, contains obviously corrupted strings like the following: `Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte`.

At some point, there probably have been used a wrong encoding for the string. Is there a way of fixing the "wrong" encoding in a string like this even when the string is already corrupted like this?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT('Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte', 'UTF8', 'US7ASCII') FROM DUAL;
```

But this leads to: `Pachtvertrag ����ber eine Gastst����tte`, while it should actually be `Pachtvertrag über eine Gaststätte`.

Another idea of mine was to somehow convert the string to bytes first (e.g. by using `TO_SINGLE_BYTE`) but this didn't lead to the desired result, either.

Comment: Actually the data looks correct (i.e. it seems to be proper UTF-8), just your Client **displays** it wrong. Which tool do you use to select the data? What is your database character set?

Comment: You can try `SELECT n'Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte' FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I actually doubt that, because usually, umlauts are displayed correctly: `SELECT 'äöü' FROM DUAL` leads to `äöü`. Nevertheless, I tried changing the encoding (I'm using Toad for Oracle 15.0.97.1178), but this didn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: @MT0 This does nothing for me - what is the idea behind that approach?

Comment: And what is your  database character set?

Comment: If the client you are using is not displaying the extended characters for `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2`  data types due to an incompatible character set then it may display correctly for `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR2` data types if they are using a different character set.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Looking at `select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'`, my charset seems to be `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: `CONVERT('Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte', 'UTF8', 'US7ASCII')` is wrong in several points. Syntax is `CONVERT(<input>, <dest_char_set>, <source_char_set>)`, so it would be the opposite. `US7ASCII` is 7-Bit ASCII, it does not support german Umlauts either. And UTF-8 in Oracle is named `AL32UTF8` but this is most likely not relevant.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit This tutorial: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-convert/ says that converting "a string from ANSI to UTF8" is done like this: `SELECT CONVERT( 'ABC', 'utf8', 'us7ascii' ) FROM dual`. Thus, I used the syntax above.

Comment: @MT0 Tried using `TO_NCHAR` now, but this does nothing to the string, either.

Comment: Are you sure? When you get a result like `'Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte'` then usually there could be two reasons: 1) The data is correct but your client displays it wrong - this problem usually does not appear with TOAD, because TOAD is very smart in that. 2) Your database uses a single-byte character set (e.g. `WE8MSWIN1252`) but your client application was using UTF-8 - this problem should not appear either, because when your client uses UTF-8 and your database also then there can't be any mismatch. You  must have done something very special to insert the data like this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I wasn't the person inserting the data, actually. I am just working with the existing data. I suspect that this corruption happened at another point in time and the string has just been copy-pasted into the database in its corrupted form already. Thus, Toad just assumes that the strings are correct the way they are. I am therefore looking for a way to convert this "correctly-displayed wrong string" into a "correctly-displayed correct string", if you will.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Your hint with the single-byte character set was obviously the correct one! A simple `CONVERT('Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte', 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'UTF8')` did the trick! Seems like the original text was encoded as ISO 8859-1 which is WE8ISO8859P1 in ORACLE. If you want, you can add this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character set `US7ASCII` does not support special characters and you must flip the character sets.

So, correction statement must be like

```
CONVERT('Pachtvertrag Ã¼ber eine GaststÃ¤tte', 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'AL32UTF8')
```

Just a note, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15 and Windows-CP1252 (`WE8MSWIN1252`) are very similar. See [ISO 8859-15 vs. -1 vs. Windows-1252 vs. Unicode](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-15#ISO_8859-15_vs._-1_vs._Windows-1252_vs._Unicode) and pick the correct encoding.

Comment: Just a note, it seems to work just fine with both `AL32UTF8` and `UTF8` in the given case.

Comment: Yes, as long as you use only the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), i.e Unicode characters less than  `U+FFFF` these two character set are identical.