# How to convert special characters in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8

I have to import data on table and through an interface and these datas come out with a different spelling as what I was intended to. For example, I got `pÃ¨re` instead of `pÃ¨re`, `PrÃ©sident` instead of `Président` and `lâ€™Aiguille` instead of `l'Aiguille`.

I tried the solution found here [Fix corrupted characters (e.g. umlauts) in a string using ORACLE SQL and convert it to proper UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569503/fix-corrupted-characters-e-g-umlauts-in-a-string-using-oracle-sql-and-convert) but it doesn't seem to work with some characters.

For example, `select convert('PrÃ©sident','WE8MSWIN1252', 'AL32UTF8') from dual` works and returns `Président`.
Though, `select convert('pÃ¨re','WE8MSWIN1252', 'AL32UTF8') from dual` returns `pÿre` instead of `père` and `select convert('lâ€™Aiguille','WE8MSWIN1252', 'AL32UTF8') from dual` returns `l¿™Aiguille` instead of `l'Aiguille`

EDIT : When I execute the query `SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`
I get `WE8ISO8859P15` .
When I execute the query `SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';` I get `AL16UTF16`

Do you have a way to convert properly these characters please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You application needs to handle UTF-8 and there's at least one piece in the processing workflow that doesn't, either because it's unable to or because it's configured to use a different encoding. You need to identify and fix that element. Breaking data to later fix it is not going to work.

Comment: hello, the problem is that I don't have access to these information. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the processing workflow :(

Comment: Don't insert your strings using the `WE8MSWIN1252` character set and then try to convert them to UTF-8 later. Insert them as UFT-8 and then read them as UTF-8. If you have already inserted them as a non-UFT-8 character set then the damage is already done and the data may not be recoverable.

Comment: So, you start with the information already loaded in your Oracle table?

Comment: the information is loaded in my Oracle table as shown in the exemples above. And then, the interface allow us to use oracle function to convert some characters.

Comment: MT0, I don't have control to that unfortunately, I try to import them from a txt file which is interpreted as shown on the examples above. So that's why I try to convert them with a function :(

Comment: Please update the question and include this information: 1) The column type. 2) The output of `SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` and `SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';`.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, I just updated the request.

Comment: Actually all information you gave does not matter. The main issue is "...come out with a different spelling as what I was intended to" What is this spelling (or better: what is this character set or what is this encoding)? Without knowing this, it will be very difficult to insert the data properly into your database.

Comment: How do you try to import the data?

Comment: It is a txt file containing the special characters such as ```père``` , ```l'Aiguille``` and ```Président```

Comment: I import the file via an application which is connected to an Oracle database. And when I use this import tool the special characters are not correctly interpreted.

Comment: "via an application" does not answer my question. What is this application? How did you configure it? In this "application" you have to specify the character set of your input text file.

Comment: It's not up to my service to parameter this application, so I cannot reply to this question unfortunately. I only have access to the application as a user and I can import data on the database via an import interface. I cannot change the character set of this application since I don't have the access to do so.

Comment: Don't you have a trick similar to the convert function, shared on the thread I share on my initial post?

Comment: No, there is not always a magic trick that can fix bad data - sometimes it is just broken because someone did something wrong when they inserted it. If you convert to-and-from a different character set then if there is any point where the temporary character set does not support encoding the characters then your data will be mangled and is likely to be unrecoverable. Fix the application that inserts the data so it reads the file as UTF-8 data and inserts the UTF-8 data into a database column that supports UTF-8 encoded data (possibly an `NVARCHAR2` column given your database encoding).

Comment: hello MT0, can you tell me why ```Ã¨``` cannot be converted to ```è``` with the convert function?

Comment: As also stated by MT0, you cannot insert crap into your database and then think you can fix it afterwards. Maybe you can convert the input file with a tool like [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

Comment: If, as an example, you have a character set representing 10,000 characters and a second character set representing 1,000 characters and you convert from the first character set to the second then on average 10 characters in the first character set will be converted to 1 character in the second. If you try to convert it back then you do not know which of the 10 characters to convert it to. Now you could map one character in the first character set to two characters in the second character set but there still may not be a 1-to-1 correspondence so you are still left unsure how to convert it back.

Comment: Continuing the example, if `ÿ` and `è` in the UTF-8 character set both convert to `Ã¨` in the WE8MSWIN1252 character set then when you convert back you don't know which to convert it to and if the conversion function picks `ÿ` when you want `è` then you will get a different output to the input. As I said, bad data is not always fixable.